# Is there any workspace analysis tool in ROS for a robot arm?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 7 DOF robot arm and i want to use it to do table top manipulations. so firstly i want to do a workspace analysis for the arm so that i can know how to place the table such that the arm can reach any point of the table. i've tried a brute-force way, that is, to increase each joint's rotation by a certain step and then use FK to get a position. but since my arm is of 7 DOF, this method is very very slow and the final result contains too many data for matlab to display. i also know that there is a monto-carlo based method, but don't know how to realize it. so i just wonder if there is any tool/package in ROS to do the workspace analysis. it would be even better to show the workspace in rviz.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46052/is-there-any-workspace-analysis-tool-in-ros-for-a-robot-arm?/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about the availability of what you request for ROS/rviz (hopefully someone else will shed light on this), but OpenRAVE offers functionality for this. It is pretty easy to convert a URDF based robot arm to the OpenRAVE format, so you could give that a shot. I covered the conversion process as part of a answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12846/could-ik-solver-called-by-arm_navigation-auto-generated-file-work-for-5-dof-manipulator/).

See also the [kinematicreachability](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/openravepy/databases.kinematicreachability/) OpenRAVE docs and the other [database generators](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/databases/#openrave-database-generators).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-17**:
Thanks man. i will take a look at openrave

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A package called reuleaux can satisfy your requirements.

---

Originally posted by [pyni_sjtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28882/pyni_sjtu/) with karma: 36 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on 2017-10-03**:
http://wiki.ros.org/reuleaux